# Why are footnote marks not appearing with consistent sizes in ConTeXt?

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, context

I have a document with several footnotes. I used `\setupnotation[footnote]` and `\setupnote[footnote]` to define the font size for the footnote items:

- The font size of the number appearing in the text.
- The font size of the number appearing in the footnote.
- The font size of the text appearing in the footnote.

Here is my code:

```
 \definefontsize[a]
 \definefontsize[b]
 \definefontsize[c]
 \definefontsize[d]
 \definefontsize[e]
 \definefontsize[f]
 \definefontsize[g]

 \setupbodyfontenvironment[default]
    [%
        a=0.833,
        b=1.000,
        c=1.200,
        d=1.440,
        e=1.728,
        f=2.073,
        g=2.488%
    ]

 \def\textsmall{\ssa}
 \def\textmedium{\ssb}
 \def\textlarge{\ssg}


 \setupnotation[footnote][style=\textsmall, headstyle=\textsmall]
 \setupnote[footnote][textstyle=\textmedium]

 \starttext

    {\textlarge This is text\footnote{This is a footnote}.}

 \stoptext
```

When I compile this, the font size of the number "1" appearing in the body text is larger than the font size of the number "1" appearing at the bottom of the page in the footnote. I took a screen shot with GIMP and found that the number in the bottom was two pixels. Yet, both `style=\textsmall` and `headstyle=\textsmall`, so these should both be set to `0.833` size.

How can I make sure these footnote marks are consistent in font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a chance to obtain the same size of the footnote mark in the text as well as in the footnote one has to ensure that `headstyle` in `\setupnotation` and `textstyle` in `\setupnote` are the same.

However, this is not the whole solution.  The whole footnote is again scaled by the parameter `bodyfont` in `\setupnote`.  The default is `bodyfont=small` which results in a downscaling.  If you want to have exactly the sizes you specified using the `...style` parameters, set `bodyfont=normal`.

```
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [
    style=\ssa,    % footnote content
    headstyle=\ssb,% footnote mark in the footnote
  ]

\setupnote
  [footnote]
  [
    bodyfont=normal,% footnote content
    textstyle=\ssb, % footnote mark in the text
  ]

\starttext

  {\ssd This is text\footnote{This is a footnote}.}

\stoptext
```

[image]